# Retrieving results from Iron-Ajax call

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm getting started with Polymer particularly with iron-ajax for retrieving JSON data from an ASP.Net WebAPI service. I'm able to make a call to the service, however I'm not able to get to the results returned from the service.

Here's my iron-ajax element:

```
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="http://local.webapi2.com/api/values"
               headers='{ "Key": "d72ad080-e3dd-43ea-ba95-0cd2a5a58bb1" }'
               handle-as="json"
               content-type="application/json"
               method='GET'
               verbose="true"
               on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
```

Here's my handleResponse function:

```
    handleResponse: function (jsonFromServer)
    {
        console.log('response from server:', jsonFromServer);
    }
```

Here's my WebAPI endpoint:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6" };
    }
}
```

I'm using the Firefox browser. Using Firebug's Net tab, I can see the call to http://local.webapi2.com/api/values and I can see the results returned:

```
["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6"]
```

However, in Firebug's Console, I only see this:

```
response from server: response
```

Where 'response' is an object that appears to be detail information about 'iron-ajax' element itself.  The expected results data is never displayed in the console.  Furthermore, the Response tab of the WebAPI call in the console has null as a value.  There's not even a JSON tab in the detail under the WebAPI call in the console.

I'm not sure why the Net tab has the complete and accurate results as you would expect, but the Console tab nulls out and I'm presented with a 'response' object.

I'm experiencing this same situation in Chrome too.

What am I missing? Is it a configuration issue? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually using ASP.NET Web API too and haven't had this issue.

The problem could be this line -

```
handleResponse: function (jsonFromServer)
{
    console.log('response from server:', jsonFromServer);
}
```

The aregument is not the direct return value but the entire *event object*. So maybe try -

```
handleResponse: function (e)
{
    console.log('response from server:', e.detail.response); // or e.detail.xhr.repsone
}
```